# Is it possible to use read_csv to read only specific lines?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a csv file that looks like this:

```
TEST  
2012-05-01 00:00:00.203 ON 1  
2012-05-01 00:00:11.203 OFF 0  
2012-05-01 00:00:22.203 ON 1  
2012-05-01 00:00:33.203 OFF 0  
2012-05-01 00:00:44.203 OFF 0  
TEST  
2012-05-02 00:00:00.203 OFF 0  
2012-05-02 00:00:11.203 OFF 0  
2012-05-02 00:00:22.203 OFF 0  
2012-05-02 00:00:33.203 OFF 0  
2012-05-02 00:00:44.203 ON 1  
2012-05-02 00:00:55.203 OFF 0
```

and cannot get rid of the `"TEST"` string.

Is it possible to check whether a line starts with a date and read only those that do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
import pandas

s = StringIO()
with open('file.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        if not line.startswith('TEST'):
            s.write(line)
s.seek(0) # "rewind" to the beginning of the StringIO object

pandas.read_csv(s) # with further parameters…
```

Answer (score 4):

When you get the `row` from the `csv.reader`, and when you can be sure that the first element is a string, then you can use

```
if not row[0].startswith('TEST'):
    process(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html?highlight=read_csv#pandas.io.parsers.read_csv

> skiprows : list-like or integer
>   Row numbers to skip (0-indexed) or number of rows to skip (int)

Pass `[0, 6]` to skip rows with "TEST".

Comment: I am afraid he knows how such lines look like, not their indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, since I just ran into this problem also:

```
import pandas as pd
import subprocess
grep = subprocess.check_output(['grep', '-n', '^TITLE', filename]).splitlines()
bad_lines = [int(s[:s.index(':')]) - 1 for s in grep]
df = pd.read_csv(filename, skiprows=bad_lines)
```

It's less portable than @eumiro's (read: probably doesn't work on Windows) and requires reading the file twice, but has the advantage that you don't have to store the entire file contents in memory.

You could of course do the same thing as the grep in Python, but it'd probably be slower.